# Define Haskell function with let fun x = x + 1 form

Tags: haskell

If I have a function as following:

```
f::[a]->Integer
f  [] = 0
f (x:cx) = 1 + (f cx)
```

how can I define the function inside the main with 'let'?

I know I can define a function inside main: e.g.

```
let f x = x + 1
```

but how I'm pattern-matching for `"f [] = 0"`?

Thanks

Comment: note that `f` here is (almost) exactly the same as the standard function `length`, which is defined in Prelude and therefore available to all programs with no import required. (The only difference in that the Prelude function yields an `Int` not an `Integer`, but that only matters if you're calculating the length of lists greater than around 2^32, which I really hope you're not. And even in that case you can use `genericLength` from `Data.List`.) So there's no need to define this yourself. (Unless it's a homework question to implement it, but then it's strange to have to put it in a `let`.)

Comment: Thanks for notifying me there is function called 'length' in Haskell. My question has nothing to do with the function. My question is "how to define a function inside the main with pattern matching" @melpomene understands my question, and gave out the right answer.

Comment: @melpomene  gave out good answer because he/she know what he/she are talking about. he/she also mentioned the indentation of in Haskell because Haskell indentation is tricky for beginner

Comment: @1234 Do you understand the difference between an attempt and a working solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still do it the same way:

```
main =
    let f  [] = 0
        f (x:cx) = 1 + (f cx)
    in
    print (f "abc")
```

or

```
main =
    let
        f  [] = 0
        f (x:cx) = 1 + (f cx)
    in
    print (f "abc")
```

The crucial part is that the `f`s in the two equations must line up and be indented more than `let`.